# FLVPlayback fullscreen button not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, macos, safari

In my flash video using FLVPlayback, clicking the fullscreen button doesn't do anything, either in the html-loaded version or (more troublingly) when running locally.  I've set "allowFullscreen" to true in the object and the embed tags in the html version.  There are no errors in the flash console when running locally.  [Example.](http://e1.simplecdn.net/newview/simplecdn_test.html)

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: What version of the Flash Player is your browser using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the fullscreen button the FLVPlayback controls, that works for me.
I'm using Firefox 3.0.11 on Mac OSX 10.4.11

If you're:
testing the browser
have the allowFullscreen set to true for both object and embed tags
everything should be fine.

I found the example code for the [displayState](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#displayState) property handy:

```
function createMouseListener(event:Event):void {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleFullScreen);
        }        

function toggleFullScreen(event:MouseEvent):void {
            if(stage.displayState == "fullScreen") 
stage.displayState = "normal"
else
stage.displayState = "fullScreen"
        }
```

Then again, you can do that in one line since you're using the FLVPlayback component's
[enterFullScreenDisplayState](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#enterFullScreenDisplayState()) method, or with 0 lines of code if you've got a skin with a fullscreen button ( which you do :) )

**I've noticed that in the html file, allowFullscreen is set to "1" instead of true in the object tag and "true" in the embed tag. I remember different browsers are using different tags. I guess firefox is using embed since it works for me. If it doesn't work, you might be using Internet Explorer ( which I can't test on at the moment ). Try setting allowFullscreen to "true" in the object tag as well.**

Goodluck !